# How to find Subnet of the given IP using perl cgi?

Tags: perl, unix, cgi, subnet

I need to find the subnet of any IP that user entered. I am executing the "`ypcat -k netmasks.byaddr`" unix command in perl to find netmasks. It is working fine in command line execution. But it is not working while executing in webserver.

The below is the code.

```
use strict;
use CGI;
my $page=new CGI;

print $page->header;

my $ipaddress=$page->param("ip");
my @splitted=split(/\./,$ipaddress);

my $part1=$splitted[0].".".$splitted[1].".".$splitted[2];
my $part2=$splitted[3];

my $comma1="ypcat -k netmasks.byaddr|grep -w $part1|awk '{print \$1}'|awk -F. '{print \$4}'|sort -g";
my $comm2="ypcat -k netmasks.byaddr|grep -w $part1|sort";

my @out=`$comm1`;
my @out2=`$comm2`;

my $match;my $sub;my $found;
foreach my $i(@out){
        chomp($i);
        if($part2 > $i){
                $sub=$i;
                $found=$part1.".".$sub;
        }
}

my (@matched) = grep $_=~m/$found/, @out2;
chomp(@matched);
print "@matched\n";
```

The above is the code I am using to find subnet of the given IP. In that the execution of "$comm1" and "$comm2" is failing.
Is any other way to find subnet of the user entered IP using Perl script?

Thanks, 
Madhan

Comment: what "is not working"? It would help if you showed the code you're having problems with...

Comment: Hi pavel, I have edited the question.

Comment: what error(s) do you get? (check your web server logs). One thing that's wrong is that you're not printing any HTTP-header before your output...

Comment: Hi pavel...., there is no error in server logs. The output is null. But, the command line execution is returning perfectly. I forget to mention http header here but not in my code.

Comment: Did you print the header as pavel suggested?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NetAddr::IP](https://metacpan.org/module/MIKER/NetAddr-IP-4.069/IP.pm)  module for this job as given below:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use NetAddr::IP;

my $page = new CGI;
print $page->header;
my $ipaddress = $page->param("ip");
my $ip = NetAddr::IP->new($ipaddress);
print "The address is ", $ip->addr, " with mask ", $ip->mask, "\n" ;
```